# UIView Animation - Animates properly but when comes again to the same position

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have 2 `UIView` both having `UITextField` each in a view. I'm animating first `UIView` from left to right and second view is tailing it. So it looks like that first view went and second view came in for further work. This works perfectly fine but when I clicked on second's `UIView`'s textfield then the fist `UIView` comes back to the screen. The code is as below

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
    var resendViewNewFrame = self.resendView.frame
    resendViewNewFrame.origin.x -= resendViewNewFrame.size.width

    var confirmViewNewFrame = self.confirmView.frame
    confirmViewNewFrame.origin.x = 0
    self.resendView.frame = resendViewNewFrame
    self.confirmView.frame = confirmViewNewFrame
    self.mobileNumberTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}, completion: nil)
```

How can I make sure that the first screen doesn't come to the screen again. Basically First view's X position after animation becomes -width of the screen.

Comment: Do you have some autolayot constraints?

Comment: can you please attach the any image or gif. So can get the better idea\

Comment: Yes. I have constraints.

Comment: @uzairdhada if you have constraints, you should be animating them. Not the frame.

Comment: As @RakeshaShastri mentioned, you have to update the constant value of constraint to change the position and need to call `layoutIfNeeded()` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are using **constraints** when you configure the view first time. Then, you are changing/animating the **frames** of the views. That works if you will not layout the view again. But probably what it does, it somehow **layouts** the view by itself. So, it brings views to constrained places in first time.

What you can do is, change constraints **before** the `UIView.animate` functions call. And do `self.layoutIfNeeded` inside `UIView.animate animations` closure.

Comment: No, You need to change the constraint before the animation closure and layout the views in the closure.

Comment: Yeah, @Desdenova is right, change before closure, is the best approach to change constraint. Desdenova, would you like edit my answer ? Or I will do it.

Comment: It's better if you do.